# Fast API, test endpoints by Postman

Tags: python, authentication, fastapi

I want to test some endpoints, in particular `sign-in` endpoint by using Postman. But every time I send request I get en error whether 422 or 401 (the login and password are correct).
Is it pissible to test `sign-in` with Postman?
[image]

[image]

```
router = APIRouter(
    prefix='/auth'
)
@router.post('/sign-in', response_model=Token)
def sign_in(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(), service: AuthService = Depends()):
    return service.authenticate_user(form_data.username, form_data.password)
```

Comment: Yuoe have an [Return] char in login field.

Postman is quite tricky with regards of user experience ;)